# No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'

Tags: android, android-actionbar

below is my xml file.It gives me err saying thaty "error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'."

```
<!--
    Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
    res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
-->

<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>
```

Comment: What is your minSdkVersion in manifest ?

Comment: android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `parent` attribute to `parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"`

Answer (score 3):

Right-click your project in the Package Explorer > select Properties > select Android > and set Project Build Target to API level 14 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click your project->properties->Android, then Add android-support-v7-appcompat

You can import this library from your android-sdk folder->extras->android->support->v7->appcompat