# How to fix errors in styles.xml in android?

Tags: android

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

//The above is my first Style.xml//

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme for API 11+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from res/values/styles.xml on API 11+ devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

//The above is my second Style.xml//

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
        res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

//The above is my third Style.xml//

I got error in above three styles.The error I am getting is I mentioned below.

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
```

ERROR

```
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'.    styles.xml  /CricketApp/res/values  line 7  Android AAPT Problem

error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'.    styles.xml  /CricketApp/res/values-v14  line 8  Android AAPT Problem

error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'.    styles.xml  /CricketApp/res/values-v11  line 7  Android AAPT Problem
```

Comment: add `appcompat_v7 lib` in your project....

Comment: @MD he wants to use Holo theme, why should he add appcompat?

Comment: do `"android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27121847/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-androidtheme-holo-light-darkacti)

Answer (score 0):

Add appcompact_v7 lib OR use style from android resource